# Is it possible to redirect the output of a batch file inside the script?

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

I would like to set the standard output of a batch script to go to a file.  I would like to do this inside the script if possible.

**Note:** I do *not* want to do this: `foo.bat > StdOut.txt`

I would like to do something inside the script to redirect the output to a file
For example:

foo.bat

```
:: Redirect standard output to StdOut.txt
:: Insert batch code to do what I want here.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way of doing it is the following.  Use the `call` command to execute a label in the script.  **Edit** I realized the first version I posted does not seem to work in a cmd.exe prompt (I was using TCC).  The following seems to work in both command processors:

```
@echo off
call :testitout > t.tmp
goto:eof

:testitout
echo Hi There
echo Goodbye
```

Comment: @SwDevMan81, The reason I looked is because I have wanted to do this in the past and never knew how.  But your question prompted my brain to remember that the call command could call a label in the batch file, which made me wonder if this trick would work.  So I only just now learned this.

Comment: Yeah I definitely wont have thought of this.  Looks like we both learned something new today :)

Comment: I think you also have to redirect error output to standard output to see everything.

Comment: It's great, but there is a number of problems with this solution, especially if you're converting an existing script:    

* Utilities that detect redirection and behave differently (e.g., `more`) will think they are run interactively
* Positional variables that contain arguments to the script will not be available after the `call` unless you explicitly `call :testitout %*`

May be there are more. The first one is currently driving me nuts... Anyone got a solution for that? I can't think of anything better than running `more /p >&2` when redirecting as `call :testitout >t.tmp 2>&1`.

Answer (score 1):

> is the standard, so you're more-or-less stuck with that; however, you can move it inside the batch file:

foo.bat:

```
@echo off
@echo Start File > StdOut.txt
@dir >> StdOut.txt
@echo End File >> StdOut.txt
```