# Batch - How can I redirect stderr and stdout from within the batch script itself?

Tags: batch-file

In Unix shell scripting it is possible to redirect the stderr and stdout from the within script itself as below:

```
#!/bin/ksh
# script_name: test.sh
export AUTO_LOGFILE=`basename $0 .sh`.log
# stdout and stderr Redirection. This will save the old stdout on FD 3, and the old stderr on FD 4.
exec 3>&0 4>&1 >>$AUTO_LOGFILE 2>&1
echo "Hello World"
# The above echo will be printed to test.log
```

In effect, test.sh can be executed simply as:

```
test.sh
```

Instead of:

```
test.sh >> test.log 2>&1
```

I am trying to do the similar in batch script. My batch code is as below:

```
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
REM script_name=test.bat
set AUTO_LOGFILE=%~n0.log
REM How to do the stdout and stderr redirection from within the script itself here?
```

How can I redirect stderr and stdout from within the batch script itself? What I'm more interested in is converting this unix shell script statement into equivalent batch code:

```
exec 3>&0 4>&1 >>$AUTO_LOGFILE 2>&1
```

Comment: Your question is a duplicate from this: [Is it possible to redirect the output of a batch file inside the script?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607390/is-it-possible-to-redirect-the-output-of-a-batch-file-inside-the-script

Comment: @Mac I need to execute many commands and call many subroutines in the latter part of the script. I can not simply do that in the function testitout as mentioned in the answer in the link which you provided.

Comment: Not sure about it, but if you had a subroutine, just like your main that calls the other subroutines, would not that work?

Comment: @MAC Hmm... will look into that. But what I'm more interested in is conversion of this unix shell script statement into equivalent batch code:

    exec 3>&0 4>&1 >>$AUTO_LOGFILE 2>&1

Comment: I thought 0 was stdin, 1 stdout, and 2 stderr. So shouldn't your exec line read `exec 3>&1 4>&2 >>$AUTO_LOGFILE 2>&1`?

Comment: @SachinS: Just answer if you want to send both stderr and stdout to the file, or just one of them and the other to the screen (which ones?)...

Comment: @Aacini Both should be sent to the same file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **test.bat** Batch file below is *functionally equivalent* to your Unix script, that is, it send all standard output to the log file and error output to the screen:

```
@echo off
if defined reEntry goto reEntry
set reEntry=TRUE

set AUTO_LOGFILE=%~N0.log
rem stdout Redirection. Leave stderr as is.

"%~F0" %* >>%AUTO_LOGFILE%

:reEntry
set reEntry=
echo "Hello World"
rem The above echo will be printed to test.log
rem and error messages will be printed to the screen:
verify badparam
```

***Adenddeum:***

I thought the OP wants to *separate* stdout from stderr to see error messages in the screen, but perhaps I misunderstood him. To send both stdout and stderr to the file, use the line below as dbenham noted in his comment:

```
"%~F0" %* >>%AUTO_LOGFILE% 2>&1
```

Or in the even easier way already suggested in a comment above:

```
@echo off
set AUTO_LOGFILE=%~N0.log
rem stdout and stderr Redirection.

call :Main %* >>%AUTO_LOGFILE% 2>&1
goto :EOF

:Main
echo "Hello World"
rem The above echo will be printed to test.log
```

However, if the purpose is to *distingish* error messages from normal output, then it may be done *in the same screen* via this trick:

```
"%~F0" %* 2>&1 1>&3 | findstr /N /A:4E "^"
```

This way the error messages appears preceded by a line number in yellow color on red background. This method may be directly used in several cases; for example, in the compilation of any programming language source program:

```
anycompiler %1 2>&1 1>&3 | findstr /N /A:4E "^"
```

Comment: +1  But, I think the OP wants to redirect stderr to the same file, so `"%~F0" %* >>%AUTO_LOGFILE% 2>&1`. Also, Windows automatically saves the redirected handles to the first available unassigned handles. So unless prior redirections have occurred, the original stdout is saved in handle 3 and stderr in handle 4. So `echo This will go to the console (stdout) >&3` will do just that.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the lines in parentheses

```
(
  REM How to do the stdout redirection from within the script itself here?
  ECHO is this redirected?
  ECHO yes it is
) >out.txt
```