# How to redirect commandline ouput to both file and sysout in windows

Tags: cmd, output

Is there a way to redirect an output inside a windows .bat to a file AND to the sysout at the same time. At the moment I am using the answer from this question: "[Is it possible to redirect the output of a batch file inside the script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607390/is-it-possible-to-redirect-the-output-of-a-batch-file-inside-the-script)"
to redirect the output to a file, but i am using >> to append on the log-file if the process runs multiple times. The only problem is that i now get no ouput at sysout, which i also would like to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `tee` program, which does exactly what you want. It is standard on unix, but alas, not so on Windows.

There are free ports of unix utilities for windows from Gnu: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm. Included is the `tee` command.

Or you could use a simple hybrid JScript/batch TEE.BAT utility that I posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10719322/1012053.

Assuming TEE.BAT is in your current directory, or better yet, somewhere within your PATH, then:

```
yourCommand | tee "outpuFile.txt"
```